# Default value on mappings AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

What would be a good strategy to have a default value on mappings?

I.E.

I have a parameter called `country`

Based on that `country` I reference a DNS using mappings

```
"Mappings" : {
   "DNS":{
     "us" : {"dns" : "mypage.us.com", "ttl" : "600"},
     "mx" : {"dns" : "mypage.default.com", "ttl" : "300"},
     "ar" : {"dns" : "mypage.default.com", "ttl" : "300"},
     "br" : {"dns" : "mypage.default.com", "ttl" : "300"}
   }
}
```

If `us` it's been mapped:

```
{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "DNS", { "Ref" : "country" }, "dns" ]}
```

I get `"mypage.us.com"` for the other countries I've created a huge list of countries with a default value `mypage.default.com`, in the future, this values will be changing and we will be adding more countries, is there a better approach to this?

Comment: perhaps a combination of the Fn::If and Fn::FindInMap? 

(i.e. use the if condition, so that if it does NOT find the value in the map -- not sure what the outcome is then -- you assign your default value... ? )

Answer (score 12):

The only way I was able to do this was to chain `Fn::If` statements instead of using the map. I tried using a combination of `Fn::If` and `Fn::FindInMap` but `Fn::FindInMap` will always raise an error it if can't find the mapping.

Therefore the only solution for me was to resort to using something like the following (for me it was setting ecs memory based on instance type):

```
Conditions:
  IsT2Micro: !Equals [!Ref InstanceType, "t2.micro"]
  IsT2Small: !Equals [!Ref InstanceType, "t2.small"]
  ...

taskdefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ...
      Memory: !If [ IsT2Micro, 900, !If [ IsT2Small, 1900, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since early 2023, there is a better approach with the `defaultValue` in the AWS LanguageExtensions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap-enhancements.html

You can now do:

```json
{ "Fn::FindInMap" : 
[ "DNS", { "Ref" : "country" }, "dns", 
{"DefaultValue": "defaultdomain"} ]}
```

If you add the

```yaml
Transform:
  - 'AWS::LanguageExtensions'
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Steve Smith's answer.

Cloudformation always expects a valid mapping, even behind a missed logic gate.

You can combine !Sub and !If for a fair amount of flexibility though.

For example, we do this for dynamic staging ECS Env vars:

```yaml
Parameters:

  Env:
    Type: String

  Branch:
    Type: String

  DevelopUrl:
    Type: String
    Default: "develop.example.com"

  MasterUrl:
    Type: String
    Default: "master.example.com"

  ...(ECS Resource)
          Environment:
            
            - !If
              - IsStaging
              - Name: SOME_CALLBACK_URL
                Value: !Sub
                  - "https://${Url}/some-callback-endpoint"
                  - Url: !If [ IsDevelop, !Ref DevelopUrl, !If [ IsMaster, !Ref MasterUrl, !GetAtt MyLoadBalancer.DNSName ] ]
              - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score -5):

Cloud Formation helps create AWS resources once in the beginning of their life. You can also do updates with it, but I think in your case it sounds like you'll be better off building your DNS config logic into your application. Maybe create a Database table in DynamoDB with the mapping data. You could pass the Country value into the servers as an environment variable, and have them query the DynamoDB table on launch based on their environment variable.

Alternatively, you can have Cloud Formation invoke a Lambda function when it launches a new stack to query DynamoDB to get the value of the DNS config based on the country so you don't have to keep modifying your stack JSON every time there's a new entry and don't have to change your application.

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to codify data like DNS mappings in a stack like the OP requested. With CI/CD in AWS CopePipeline it's simply a case of pushing a new commit with the updated mappings. This answer states that AWS Lambdas launch new stacks, which while technically possible is not advised and not at all what the OP is asking about.

Answer (score -5):

In your mapping, add a default entry:

```
"Mappings" : {
   "DNS":{
     "us" : {"dns" : "mypage.us.com", "ttl" : "600"},
     "mx" : {"dns" : "mypage.mx.com", "ttl" : "300"},
     "default" : {"dns" : "mypage.default.com", "ttl" : "300"}
   }
}
```

Then create a condition (YAML):

```
Conditions:
  HasSpecialDNS: !Or:
    - !Equals [!Ref country, "us"]
    - !Equals [!Ref country, "mx"]
```

Then change the 2nd parameter of FindInMap to:

```
{ "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "DNS", { "Fn::If": ["HasSpecialDNS", {"Ref" : "country"}, "default" ]}, "dns" ]}
```

Or YAML:

```
Fn::FindInMap:
  - DNS
  - !If ["HasSpecialDNS", !Ref country, "default" ]
  - "dns"
```

Comment: Sorry, this solution does not work at this moment. The FindInMap can only support "Ref" and "FindInMap" function in the parameters.